# how to get imagepaths into bitmaps from drawable folder?

Tags: android, bitmap

i have two images in the drawable folder. i want to display them in full screen and if u slide then next image should come. this is the code i am using:

```
import com.ssb.crackssb.R;

    import java.util.ArrayList;


       import android.app.Activity;
       import android.content.Context;
       import android.graphics.Bitmap;
        import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
          import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
      import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

      import android.widget.ImageView;
       import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

    public class FullScreenImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Activity _activity;
private  int[]  _imagePaths= {R.drawable.piq1,R.drawable.piq2};
private LayoutInflater inflater;

// constructor
public FullScreenImageAdapter(Activity activity,
        int[] imagePaths) {
    this._activity = activity;
    this._imagePaths = imagePaths;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this._imagePaths.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imgDisplay;


    inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.piq, container,
            false);

    imgDisplay = (ImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageview);


    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imagePaths(position), options);
    imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    // close button click event


    ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout);

    return viewLayout;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

}
}
```

it is giving error in this line :

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imagePaths(position), options);
```

error is:

```
The method _imagePaths(int) is undefined for the type FullScreenImageAdapter
```

i want to load the images into my bitmap from the drawable folder. please help me.

Comment: Why are you using `decodeFile()` for drawable resources? Why are you not just using the drawable resources themselves, or perhaps using `decodeResource()` if there are some conversions that you need?

Comment: i tried using decodeResource(REs res,id). but how to use it. how to put the parameters for imagepath. i am new to android.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting that error is because you are treating _imagePaths as a method instead of an array. _imagePaths(position) should be _imagePaths[position].

You don't need to mess around with creating the bitmaps though. Since you have the resources in the drawable directory, you can just add them to the ImageViews as a reference:

Replace

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imagePaths(position), options);
imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

with

imgDisplay.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(_imagePaths[position]));

Comment: this gives 2 errors:   The method gerResources() is undefined for the type FullScreenImageAdapter  and  The method _imagePaths(int) is undefined for the type FullScreenImageAdapter

Comment: gerResources() is a method of Context, so use getApplicationContext().getResources() or use the context from the Activity that gets passed into your constructor.

Stop doing this "_imagePaths(int)"!  _imagePaths is an array. Not a method.  _imagePaths[int] is the proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

there's no need to make it so complicated, just simply:

```
viewLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.piq1);
```

**edit:**

`R.` object is a just a bunch of integers, it doesn't matter how you reference them. Here the code:

```
viewLayout.setBackgroundResource(_imagePaths[position]);
```

Comment: yeah but i wanna display 2 images not one. first image should be displayed then when you slide second one should be displayed.

Comment: then also its displaying only the first image. nothing happens when i slide